# Using rest server and websocket with elasticbeanstalk, java, cannot connect

Tags: java, nginx, websocket, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to configure nginx routing to be able to use both a rest server (using Java Spark) and Websockets (using Netty-socketIO).

It works really well locally, but cannot get it to work on aws elasticbeanstalk.

I have Java Spark listening on port 5000, which is the default from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk configures the nginx proxy to forward requests to your application on port 5000

and that works.

I listen on port 9000 for the Websocket. I did change the ELB protocol to TCP.

And still from aws docs :

> To extend Elastic Beanstalk's default nginx configuration, add .conf configuration files to a folder named .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/ in your application source bundle. Elastic Beanstalk's nginx configuration includes .conf files in this folder automatically.

which I tried without much success :

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

SocketIO-client connection string `http://beanstalk-address-here.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:9000`

In the Network tab, the request is (pending) for a time before failing.

Comment: have u enabled stickiness on target group? without it web socket cannot work I guess

Answer (score 0):

One issue thats likely is that you don't have your ELB configured correctly to except connections on port 9000.  You must configure security groups on the ELB correctly to allow connections on non-standard ports:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-connectivity-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

Why do  you use nginx if you still access your app through non-standard port

Nginx routing usually accepts all connection in one single port (usually 80/443) and based on the configuration path, it would redirect to any specific ip/port

You nginx config file should essentially have these

Nginx listen port

```
   server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;

   }
```

Redirection list

```
server{
....

location / {
        proxy_pass http://<your-app-ip>:<your-app-port>;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;   
}  

}
```

Now restart nginx

Your app url is **http://beanstalk-address-here.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:9000**

Your redirected url is **http://beanstalk-address-here.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com** (nginx will listen to port 80 and redirect to your app port)